# What are the difference of using code sign during building and submitting to app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

When you submit the app to appstore, there are two times you need to select the code sign, e.g.

1. during code build
2. during upload

What are the difference? 
What if I select two different code sign during 1 & 2

Comment: Good question! I've always assumed that the second code signing overrides the first, but I have no data to support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time xcode will verify your distribution certificate. Second time is a little bit tricky, if you are uploading the app, of course you have to use distribution codesign, but if you are building for Ad Hoc, you can select either developer certificate or distribution certificate, but the problem is that the devices you added in the distribution provisioning profile can not install this app if you use developer certificate to build the app.